# how do i tp entitys

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

how do I teleport entitys like cobblestone on the ground to a certain location do i just use teleport @e x y z or do i use teleport @e[something here] x y z does anybody know? by the way i am playing in 1.10 i know how to teleport creepers and such but not entitys like cobblestone i tried to do /tp @e x y z and /tp @e[type=cobblestone] x y z but none of them worked I need it because they have to mine a reappearing block and the entitys fly every where I want them all to center at a x y z co-ordnets

Comment: Man, I need to play more games. I read "How do I TP..." and my first thought was: "Step 1 - Go buy a dozen or so rolls of Charmin...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to teleport any dropped item, then you simply need to select them with `@e[type=Item]`. For example:

```
/tp @e[type=Item] X Y Z
```

---

If you want to teleport dropped items of a certain type (e.g: only cobblestone), then it'll take two commands.

There's no selector argument (like `type=`) that can directly detect the item name of a dropped item entity, so you'll need to first use a command that can target based on NBT data, such as `/scoreboard players tag`:

```
/scoreboard players tag @e[type=Item] add IsCobblestone {Item:{id:"minecraft:cobblestone"}}
```

You can then target the item entities based on that scoreboard tag you just added to it:

```
/tp @e[type=Item,tag=IsCobblestone] X Y Z
```

Comment: I cant belive its that simple wow xD

Comment: @Epb7304 No problem; click the check mark to the left of the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: ok im new too this sooo